# Build new towers or upgrade existing ones in Four Days?

Tags: ios, four-days

When I play the iPad game Four Days, it seems that multiple towers are sometimes less effective than less towers that are upgraded. However, I built the multiple, less powerful towers to make a long path, since the tutorial advises that longer paths give you more opportunity to shoot the enemy.

So, for the harder levels, which results in the most kills: long, less powerful paths of towers or shorter paths with upgraded towers?

And related, should you always upgrade towers as far as possible, or is it more efficient only to upgrade once?

Comment: Would appreciate if someone could add a Four Days tag.